# Growth of inverse factorial

Tags: math, factorial

Consider the inverse factorial function, f(n) = k where k! is the greatest factorial <= n. I've been told that the inverse factorial function is O(log n / log log n). Is it true? Or is it just a really really good approximation to the asymptotic growth? The methods I tried all give things very close to log(n)/log log(n) (either a small factor or a small term in the denominator) but not quite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that, when we're using O(...), constant factors don't matter, and any term that grows more slowly than another term can be dropped. `~` means "is proportional to."

If `k` is large, then `n = k! ~ k^k`. So `log n ~ k log k`, or `k ~ log n / log k` or `k ~ log n / log(log n / log k) = log n / (log log n - log log k)`. Because `n >> k` we can drop the term in the denominator, and we get `k ~ log n / log log n` so `k = O(log n / log log n)`.

Comment: Ah! I replaced k by a `log n` lower bound too quickly. Good trick with replacing k by its approximation `log n / log k`. P.S. `k! ~ k^k` is not true, only the log of them is.

Answer (score 1):

Start from [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for ln(k!) and work backwards from there. Apologies for not working the whole thing out; my brain doesn't seem to be working tonight.